# Actionscript 3 debug logging

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Is there a way to log debug messages with Actionscript 3 like log4j? i want to log user interactions in a Flash app(all the events and the user inputs).

Comment: The <a href="http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/">Clear Toolkit</a> contains log4fx. <a href="http://blog.petermolgaard.com/2008/12/16/log4flex-perhaps/">Reportedly</a> it's a complete implemetation of the log4* specs. <b>Edit:</b><br/>
Just found this. Looks like a easier to use logging system than log4fx. - http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-logging/asdoc/index.html

Comment: @Gunslinger47:i need to use Clear Toolkit in my scripts to checkout..integrating it is still a problem..I'll give back a feedback

Comment: Here is their help document, in case you haven't found it yet: [Log4Fx.pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/files/Clear%20Toolkit%20Docs/General%20Docs/Log4Fx.pdf/download)

Comment: Can't you just have the flash program write the user interactions to a notepad file? I know there's a way to do that but I don't have the code handy. Maybe do some research to find the actual code. The flash API pages tend to be somewhat helpful. To log the events just have a line in the function triggered by the event to write whatever you want, and for input put a line that writes whatever you want in the function that grabs the user input.

Answer (score 0):

With FlashPlayer 10.1 comes the global error handler. You could use this by manually sending the result to your server.

Read more about [FlashPlayer 10.1 Global error handling](http://saumyaray.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/global-error-handler-with-flash-player-10-1/).

There is nothing built-in as far as I know.